# iterating over a vector of vector of pointers

Tags: c++, vector

Hello all here are some parts of my code snippets.

I have a class Packet

```
Packet::Packet(
    double sending_time,
    uint32_t seq_no,
    uint32_t size
)
```

I create a vector of vectors(of type packets)

```
std::vector< std::vector<Packet*> > packets_for_tx_st
```

// Creating packets and pushing packets

```
for (int j=0;j<params.num_hosts;j++){
 for (uint32_t i = 0; i < params.num_packets_to_run; i++){
     Packet *p1 = new Packet(start_time, i, 64);  // Creating packets
     packets_for_tx_stat[j].push_back(p1);        // pushing packets  
    }
```

// Read the packets back (Reading the packets back, I have issues here)

```
for(uint32_t i=0;i<params.num_hosts;i++){
for(uint32_t j = 0; j < packets_for_tx_stat[i].size(); j++ ){
    std::cout<< packets_for_tx_stats[i][j]->seq_no << "\t" << packets_for_tx_stats[i][j]->start_time << "\t" << std::endl;
```

I have problem in the above step. It throws the following error.

```
  error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Packet’
```

Could someone explain what I am missing and the right way to print a vector of vector(of pointers) in the above case.

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Something is fishy with the code given.

Comment: The compiler says you're not showing us the code it's seeing.

Comment: Also, you're constructing `Packet` objects, but `Packet` does not have a 3 argument constructor, in addition to the commas separating the member variable declarations in `Packet`.  Looks like hastily typed-in code instead of the actual code you're compiling.

Comment: I have a large codebase. So I didn't copy paste my entire code. I will try to create a minimal,complete and verifiable example. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, except you have a few typos here and there. Here is a corrected version of it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

class Packet
{
public:
  Packet(double sending_time, uint32_t seq_no, uint32_t size);
  double sending_time;
  uint32_t seq_no;
  uint32_t size;
  uint32_t start_time;
};

Packet::Packet(
    double sending_time,
    uint32_t seq_no,
    uint32_t size
)
{
}



int main()
{
  std::vector< std::vector<Packet*> > packets_for_tx_stats;
  for(uint32_t i=0;i<20;i++){
    for(uint32_t j = 0; j < packets_for_tx_stats[i].size(); j++ ){
      std::cout<< packets_for_tx_stats[i][j]->seq_no << "\t" << packets_for_tx_stats[i][j]->start_time << "\t" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```